# Ajax call not working in Android Emulator Webview

Tags: java, android

I have a Webview in my Android App.

I have a scrollview with images and when you click on a image i load a page into a div.

I have tested this in a browser and it works but when I run it in the emulator it does not work?

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('file:///android_asset/preview/pure-white-kitchen.html', 'rightcolumn');"></a>


  <script type="text/javascript">

var loadedobjects=""
var rootdomain="http://"+window.location.hostname

function ajaxpage(url, containerid){
var page_request = false
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
else if (window.ActiveXObject){ // if IE
try {
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
} 
catch (e){
try{
page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
catch (e){}
}
}
else
return false
page_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
loadpage(page_request, containerid)
}
page_request.open('GET', url, true)
page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid){
if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs(){
if (!document.getElementById)
return
for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
var file=arguments[i]
var fileref=""
if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file)==-1){ //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
if (file.indexOf(".js")!=-1){ //If object is a js file
fileref=document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
}
else if (file.indexOf(".css")!=-1){ //If object is a css file
fileref=document.createElement("link")
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
}
}
if (fileref!=""){
document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
loadedobjects+=file+" " //Remember this object as being already added to page
}
}
}
</script>
```

Please help thanks

Comment: tested with different browsers like dolphin for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening up a backup of my application and testing it that on the Emulator, It worked.

A file in my application must have been corrupt.

Thanks for the advice guys.